# get amount of items consistently from list or hash

Tags: qore

I am parsing XML and am receiving either one hash or list of more hashes, see:

`qore -l xml -nX 'parse_xml("<root>
   <row><id>1</id><name>foo</name></row>
   <row><id>2</id><name>bar</name></row></root>")'`

`qore -l xml -nX 'parse_xml("<root>
   <row><id>1</id><name>foo</name></row></root>")'`

I need to know how many rows was parsed, but calling `elements` or `.size()` returns different values for list (amount of items) and hash (amount of keys!).

Is there a way ho to do it without the need to copy all values to new softlist variable?

`hash xml = prase_xml("...");
softlist tmp = xml.root.row; # makes unnecessary copy!
tmp.size();`

Thanks
O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [<value>::lsize()](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus//current/qore/lang/html/class_qore_1_1zzz8listzzz9.html#a66451c32831c9ea7086d2b9fb62df31c) pseudo-method, which returns:

- the number of elements of a list
- `1` for all other values
- `0` for `NOTHING`

ex:

```
hash<auto> xml = parse_xml(xmlstr);
int size = xml.root.row.lsize();
```